# Add field to a form with AJAX

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I try to add dynamically some field on a form when I click on a button "Add a sponsee". I search on internet how to do that with the form API but unfortunatly whitout succes. Here is my form class :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#tree'] = true; //Make the form fields a hierachical array*

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="sponsorship-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['sponsor'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('You (sponsor)'),
    ];
    $form['sponsor']['civility'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Civility'),
        '#options' => array('Miss' => $this->t('Miss'), 'Mister' => $this->t('Mister')),
        '#size' => 1,
    /* .......... */
    $form['sponsor']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send'),
    ];


    $form['sponsee'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Your sponsee'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="sponsees-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    //Default value of nb_sponsees to 1
    if ($form_state->getValue('nb_sponsee') == null) {
        $form_state->setValue('nb_sponsee', 1);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state->getValue('nb_sponsee'); $i++) {
        $form['sponsee'][$i]['civility'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Civility'),
            '#options' => array('Miss' => $this->t('Miss'), 'Mister' => $this->t('Mister')),
            '#size' => 1,
        ];
        $form['sponsee'][$i]['firstname'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Firstname'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
        ];
        $form['sponsee'][$i]['name'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
        ];
        $form['sponsee'][$i]['phone'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Phone'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
        ];
        $form['sponsee'][$i]['e_mail'] = [
            '#type' => 'email',
            '#title' => $this->t('E-mail'),
        ];
    }

    //If less of 3 sponsee we add the button
    if ($form_state->getValue('nb_sponsee') < 3) {
        $form['sponsee']['add_sponsee'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name' => 'add_sponsee',
            '#submit' => [$this, 'ajaxHandleSponseesSubmit'],
            '#value' => t('Add a sponsee'),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxHandleSponseesCallback'],
                'wrapper' => 'sponsees-fieldset-wrapper',
                'event' => 'click',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'progress' => array('message' => '', 'type' => 'throbber'),
            ),
        ];
    }

    return $form;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
        drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
}

/*
 * Custom Submit to increment nb_sponsees
 */
function ajaxHandleSponseesSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $form_state->setValue('nb_sponsee', $form_state->getValue('nb_sponsee') + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild(true);
}

/**
 * Ajax submit handler that will return the form structure
 */
public function ajaxHandleSponseesCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    return $form['sponsee'];
}
```

As you can see, when I clic on $form['sponsee']['add_sponsee'], I increment the nb_sponsees in the $form_state and rebuild the form. Then, in my AJAX callback, I return the fieldset part of the form. I've turn this in many way without success. This way seams to work with lot of situation, but not in mine. Am I missing something ?

---

Here's my form working with the help of examples modules :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#theme'] = 'sponsorship_form';
    $form['#tree'] = true; //Make the form fields a hierachical array*

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="sponsorship-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['sponsor'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('You (sponsor)'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="quick-contact__form col-xs-12 col-md-6">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    / ** Some fields... */

    $form['sponsor']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send'),
        '#attributes' => [
            'class' => ['btn btn-full']
        ],
        '#ajax' => array(
            'wrapper' => 'sponsorship-form-wrapper',
            'callback' => '::ajaxRebuildForm',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'progress' => array('message' => '', 'type' => 'throbber'),
        ),
    ];


    $nb_sponsee = $form_state->get('nb_sponsee');
    $form['sponsees'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="sponsees-fieldset-wrapper" class="quick-contact__form col-xs-12 col-md-6">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    if (empty($nb_sponsee)) {
        $nb_sponsee = 1;
        $form_state->set('nb_sponsee', $nb_sponsee);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $nb_sponsee; $i++) {

        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee'] = [
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => $this->t('Your sponsee'),
        ];

        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee']['civility'] = [
            '#prefix' => '<div class="formdetails-containHead">',
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Civility'),
            '#options' => array(1 => $this->t('Mr'), 2 => $this->t('Miss')),
            '#size' => 1,
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class' => ['formDetails--civility']
            ]
        ];
        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee']['firstname'] = [
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Firstname'),
            '#placeholder' => $this->t('Firstname'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        ];
        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee']['name'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
            '#placeholder' => $this->t('Name'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        ];
        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee']['phone'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Phone'),
            '#placeholder' => $this->t('Phone'),
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#size' => 64,
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        ];
        $form['sponsees'][$i]['sponsee']['e_mail'] = [
            '#type' => 'email',
            '#title' => $this->t('E-mail'),
            '#placeholder' => $this->t('E-mail'),
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        ];
    }

    //If less of 3 sponsee we add the button
    if ($nb_sponsee < 3) {
        $form['sponsees']['add_sponsee'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#prefix' => '<span class="containPlus">+</span>',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class' => ['btn-add-sponsee']
            ],
            '#value' => t('Add a sponsee'),
            '#submit' => array('::addSponcee'),
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::addSponceeCallback',
                'wrapper' => 'sponsees-fieldset-wrapper',
            ],
        ];
    }

    return $form;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->set('nb_sponsee', 1);
    // Display result.
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
        drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
}

/**
 * Ajax submit handler that will return the whole form structure.
 *  = callback of the complete submit of the form
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   The current state of the form.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The form structure.
 */
public function ajaxRebuildForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
 *
 * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
 */
public function addSponceeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['sponsees'];
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
 *
 * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
 */
public function addSponcee(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->set('nb_sponsee', $form_state->get('nb_sponsee') + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Comment: hi please refer https://www.drupal.org/project/examples module . you can find the example of add more .. i find its seimilar to what you are finding

Comment: I took the example from fapi_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php. It works now ! Thank you. Maybe you can post an answer mentioning this, I will accept it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module where you can find many ajax examples. One of the ajax example is of add and remove button which can help you . I feel the add and remove button example i find is relevant to the problem you are asking solution for .

Comment: You can find the demo form controller at `examples/fapi_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change like :

```
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '::ajaxHandleSponseesCallback',
)



function ajaxHandleSponseesCallback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$value = $form_state->getValue('nb_sponsee') + 1;
$form['sponsee']['#value'] = $value;
$form['sponsee']['#default_value'] = $value;
return $form['sponsee'];
}
```

You have more examples:

http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/26/ajax-form

http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/139/add-remove-fields-dynamically-using-form-api-and-ajax